# Drag my own component into sortable

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to drag my own component into a Kendo UI for Angular 2 Sortable? Basically, I'd like to drag items from one part of the page and have them added to a kendo-sortable, but not have them removed from where it was dragged from.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it is possible. And there are 2 ways to do it.

- The more complex one is implementing your [SortableService](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/api/SortableService/). That works with SortableComponent and your Component and do exactly what you need.
- Second solution is simple: Wrap your component inside a Sortable, even if it has only one item. Lets say you have SortableA with your original component inside. And SortableB - the target where you will drop the items.

  Set `[zone]="zone1"` for SortableA, and [`[acceptZones] = "zone1"`](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/api/SortableComponent/#acceptzones-string) for SortableB.
  At this point you will be able to drag the single item from SortableA to SortableB.
  The last thing is to call preventDefault in the [dataRemove event](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/api/SortableComponent/#dataremove-eventemitterdataevent) of SortableA. This will make SortableA copy items upon drop, instead of moving them.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do option 1, but option 2 doesn't seem to work.  dataRemove doesn't seem to be preventable. [http://plnkr.co/edit/o2AhaBCa8O5JyDCedaxT?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/o2AhaBCa8O5JyDCedaxT?p=preview)

Comment: As a workaround, what I've done is in the dataRemove event, I push a new copy into the source array.